# Wpf combobox custom template performance when bound to large collection

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, .net-core, .net-8.0

I have made a custom combobox with ControlTemplate,
I am really satisfied with the layout so far, but the problem is the performance of the popup when bound to large collections ,
to summarize the layout the new combobox has a label, Toggle Button and Popup

the Popup has a listbox that works as the item presenter for the new layout and a textbox "SearchBox" to filter the CollectionView,

i applied data virtualization to the listbox but i still get the performance issue

```xml
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

also something like

```cs
ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
var stackPanelTemplate = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(VirtualizingStackPanel));
ItemsPanel.VisualTree = stackPanelTemplate;
```

to the combobox ItemsPanel

the issue I get is when the Popup is about to appear it will freeze the UI for a while
and when trying to search or filter the collection with the SearchBox_TextChanged event the UI will freeze for a while

The new Layout Behavior:
[image]

This is the project repo on [Githup](https://github.com/softinitializing/SearchableComboBox.git)

Thank you !

Comment: How are you adding items? according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)  it is possible to unintentionally disable virtualization, maybe you are using different kinds of types in your item control?

Answer (score 0):

First, the `ListBox` uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` by default.

Just don't:

- set the attached property `ScrollViewer.CanContenScroll` to `false`
- add ListBoxItem containers explicitly.
  For example:

  ```
  <ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
  </ListBox>
  ```
- do not mix item containers (for example by adding a `Separator`)

Next you have to improve your filtering. You must understand that a filter has to iterate the complete collection.

1. Provide a busy indicator while you are filtering to avoid the freeze. Then filter on a different thread.
2. Consider to prefilter the collection, if possible, to reduce the initial size. For example, only provide the transactions of the last three days and apply any filters on this data set. Force the user to explicitly expand the list.
3. In the context of pre-filtering, it seems to be useless or detrimental to allow the user to specify the number of loaded items (as this is implied by the screenshot). At least ensure that this number is not related to the items that are actually added to the `ItemsSource`.
4. Consider to disable live filtering, where you filter as soon as the user types. At least provide an action that allows the user to disable it or in case of you knowing that the item list will be huge disable it and allow the user to enable it. You will yield better performance when you start the search after the user has entered the keyword (like Visual Studion search).

A solution that also supports live filtering and sorting could look as follows:

- create a data pool that contains the number of items in total. This pool could be partitioned.
- use a second collection as the actual data source and initially add the first page of e.g., 20 items to the `ItemsSource`
- Filter the pool based on the filter expression and sort the result if necessary on a background thread
- Update the source collection with the filtered and sorted result

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsBusy}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=FilterExpression}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Numbers}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
  public string FilterExpression
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(FilterExpressionProperty);
    set => SetValue(FilterExpressionProperty, value);
  }
 
  public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterExpressionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FilterExpression", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnFilterExpressionChanged));

  public bool IsBusy
  {
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value);
  }
 
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsBusy", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public ObservableCollection<int> Numbers
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(NumbersProperty);
    set => SetValue(NumbersProperty, value);
  }
 
  public static readonly DependencyProperty NumbersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Numbers", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  private object SyncLock { get; }
  private List<int> NumbersStore { get; }
  private ICollectionView NumbersStoreView { get; }
  private CancellationTokenSource FilterCancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    this.NumbersStore = new List<int>();
    this.NumbersStoreView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.NumbersStore);

    // Allow the collection to be modified on a background thread
    this.SyncLock = new object();
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this.Numbers, this.SyncLock);

    // Run initialization of huge collection on a background thread
    // to avoid long loading times were the UI is not available.
    this. Loaded += OnLoadedAsync;
  }

  public async void OnLoadedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.IsBusy = true;
    await Task.Run(Initialize);
    this.IsBusy = false;
  }

  public void Initialize()
  {
    // Initialize the data pool
    this.NumbersStore = Enumerable.Range(1, 30000).ToList();

    // Initialize the view with N items if you have implemented data pagination
    // or present an empty list that the user must fill 
    // by providing a filter expression
    // or show all items (make sure to enable UI virtualization 
    // if it is not enabled by default which is the case for 
    // e.g., for the ComboBox. ListBox has this feature enabled by default).
    foreach (int number in this.NumbersStore)
    {
      this.Numbers.Add(number);
    }
  }

  private static void OnFilterExpressionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var _this = (MainWindow)d;

    _this.FilterCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    _this.FilterCancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
    _this.FilterCancellationTokenSource  = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = _this.FilterCancellationTokenSource.Token;
    _ = Task.Run(() => _this.FilterNumbers(cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
  }

  private void FilterNumbers(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    try
    {
      // Show the busy indicator
      this.IsBusy = true;

      this.NumbersStoreView.Filter = IsItemAccepted; 
      if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        return;
      }

      this.Numbers.Clear();
      foreach (int filteredNumber in this.NumbersStoreView)
      {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
          return;
        }

        this.Numbers.Add(filteredNumber);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      this.IsBusy = false;
    }
  }

  private bool IsItemAccepted(object item) 
    => int.TryParse(this.FilterExpression, out int number) 
         && (int)item == number;
}
```

Comment: or i could replace the listbox with VirtualizingStackPanel ? it did make a difference .

Comment: The ListBox is basically a VirtualizingStackPanel. It looks like.you have layout issues.  Did you have a scrollviewer in your layou? And it's it visible? There should only be the ScrollViewer of the ListBox. And the ListBox should have a fixed size.

Comment: yes i do have the ListBox wrapped in scrollviewer  , i will remove it

Comment: Yes, please remove it. The ListBox already has its own ScrollViewer it plays the most important role in UI virtualization. The ListBox must not be allowed to stretch infinitely. The scroll bars must appear (at least the vertical bar).